# Using For Loop to insert +1 id

Tags: sql, loops, for-loop, insert

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
InspectionID   ID   Comment
1              1    Text1
1              2    Text2 
2              1    Text1   
3              1    Text1
3              2    Text2
```

Table 2:

```
InspectionID   ID   Comment
1              1    TextA
2              1    TextA 
3              1    TextA  
4              1    TextA
5              1    TextA
```

I need a FOR LOOP formula that will INSERT Table 2 into Table 1 but update the ID of Table2 to the next chronological number based on InspectionID. I expect my results to look like this:

Table 1 (Complete):

```
InspectionID   ID   Comment
1              1    Text1
1              2    Text2 
1              3    TextA
2              1    Text1
2              2    TextA
3              1    Text1
3              2    Text2
3              3    TextA
```

Can anyone help me through this, I have never done loops very well.

Thanks!

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using ?

Comment: why does order of insertion matters ?

Comment: Why would a for loop be required? Is this data actually correct? Why does Table 2 have an ID field that doesn't appear to be used as an identity? Definitely something off here...

Comment: This should be do-able in SQL without a for-loop.  Can you revise your question/tags to indicate which DBMS is that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS has support for windowed functions you can use those - no need for loops. They're a very powerful tool useful in a variety of cases.

SQL Server 2008 and above:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
(InspectionID, ID, Comment)
SELECT t1.InspectionID
      ,MAX(t1.ID) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.InspectionID ORDER BY t2.Comment)
      ,t2.Comment
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
     INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.InspectionID = t2.InspectionID
GROUP BY t1.InspectionID
        ,t2.Comment
```

Proof of concept (threw in extra row to Table2):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
(
    InspectionID INT
   ,ID INT
   ,Comment NVARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2
(
    InspectionID INT
   ,ID INT
   ,Comment NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
VALUES (1,1,'Text1')
      ,(1,2,'Text2')
      ,(2,1,'Text1')
      ,(3,1,'Text1')
      ,(3,2,'Text2')

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
VALUES (1,1,'TextA')
      ,(2,1,'TextA')
      ,(3,1,'TextA')
      ,(3,1,'TextB')
      ,(4,1,'TextA')
      ,(5,1,'TextA')

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
(InspectionID, ID, Comment)
SELECT t1.InspectionID
      ,MAX(t1.ID) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.InspectionID ORDER BY t2.Comment)
      ,t2.Comment
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
     INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.InspectionID = t2.InspectionID
GROUP BY t1.InspectionID
        ,t2.Comment

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table1
ORDER BY InspectionID, ID
```

Results:

```
InspectionID    ID  Comment
1               1   Text1
1               2   Text2
1               3   TextA
2               1   Text1
2               2   TextA
3               1   Text1
3               2   Text2
3               3   TextA
3               4   TextB
```